# InputStreamReader и OutputStreamWriter работа с байтами

Tags: android, java

После создания сокета

```
socket = new Socket(адрес, порт);
```

я создаю два потока для чтения и записи

```
sr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
sw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

Однако, их функции `read` и `write` работают только с массивом char[], то есть с двумя байтами. Что мне делать, если я хочу работать с массивом byte[] ?

Comment: Читайте непосредственно из потока, возвращаемого `socket.getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 1):

То что Вы хотите это Вот:
1)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()
2)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])

Но я бы порекомендовал посмотреть сюда:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getChannel()

Можете почитать в книге Эккеля про Философию Java, там про эти Chanel-ы достаточно развернуто рассказано

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = sr.read(buffer, 0, 256);
String message = new String(buffer, 0, length);
bytes = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
```